# How to make sure that folder got full permission

Tags: permissions, directory

I'm new to ubuntu, I asked before to get full permission to a folder and I followed this command

```
sudo mkdir /var/szDirectoryName
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/szDirectoryName
```

to get full permissions to a folder in `/var path` but when I checked it by using this command

```
ls -l /var/NameOfFolder
```

got `total 0`

I need to make sure that it got full permission already , how can I do that ?

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 user user     4096 Jan 11 18:43 folder1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Jan 11 18:42 folder2
```

does folder1 have full permission here  and folder2 does not have full permission?

Comment: To see the permissions of a *folder*, use `ls -ld /var/NameOfFolder`: the `-d` says to list directory entries instead of contents

Comment: @steeldriver thanks but number 2 here means what ? i mean in the example i posted folder1 has full permission and folder2 no ?

Comment: Take a look at [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean?rq=1)

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks!  (See last posted comment in answer)

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l /var/NameOfFolder` will give you the contents and permissions of that folder and as it apparently doesn't contain anything, you get well... *nothing...*

To get the permissions of `NameOfFolder`, do:

```
ls -ld /var/NameOfFolder
```

and you will get `NameOfFolder` with all its permissions.

**For more information, type:**

```
man ls
```

Comment: please see my edit post

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you have any further questions, [just ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)  and I would be pretty surprised you would have read [The FHS standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) already in such a short time.  Read that first, please... And don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green.

Comment: again ! but it's related to question how to make sure that folder has full permission ?

Comment: Apparently you're typing homework questions here as you don't want to read the documentation that I told you to read. [Open this link in a new tab](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MeO65BoP3VU/VLb1Q8JGBPI/AAAAAAAAGxg/48tIxC7Yjrg/w530-h284-p/Homework.gif).